# Android: Manifest merger failed

Tags: android

I seem to be getting the error of:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.> Manifest
>   merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value
>   value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 is also present at
>   [com.android.support:exifinterface:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
>   value=(25.3.1). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to
>    element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.

It seems as though this error is caused, when I include an image cropping library of: compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'

Gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproj.blogapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+' //This dependency causing error

    // FirebaseUI Database only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myproj.blogapp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        tools:node="replace"
        android:name=".SimpleBlog"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="PT Mosque"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Feed">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PostActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".timetable"
            android:label="Salah Times"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SetupActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
 compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
```

to

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
 compile ('com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'){

        exclude group: 'com.android.support'  
}
```

Comment: Error message is not mentioning  icon so there is no need to replace icon.

Comment: I'm edited my answer. mixing of versions causing this problem

Answer (score 5):

Add this to

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
Add this to

tools:node="replace"

Comment: Add to what or where?

Comment: Add to your app manifest file inside <application> tag. It will allow to override conflicting libraries when manifest files are merged. Obviously, you need to declare in your app build.gradle file the library you want to use instead of your dependency conflicting libraries. It worked for me to use compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0' instead of 26.0.1 of one of my dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Image cropper library requires older version of support library than your app. 
There's [a fresh bug filled in the issues for the library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/349) already but it's not fixed yet.

You can downgrade support library version used by your app ( to 25.3.1 ) and wait for a fix.

EDIT: you would need to lower build target accordingly. There's [another bug for build target on github](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/335).